# Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not ... on line 26

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю сайт по видеоурокам, там же код дополнили, на видео получилось, у меня выдало ту же ошибку(((

> `Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in D:\appserver\www\shop\db_fns.php on line 26`

Вот  код:

```
<?

function db_connect()
{
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'shop_user';
    $pswd = 'admin123';
    $db   = 'shop';

    $connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf-8");
    if (!$connection || !mysql_select_db($db, $connection)) {
        return false;
    }
    return $connection;
}

function db_result_to_array($result)
{
    $res_array = array();

    $count = 0;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $res_array[$count] = $row;
        $count++;
    }
    return $res_array;
}

function get_products()
{
    db_connect();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC";    
    $result = mysql_query($query);    
    $result = db_result_to_array($result);

    return $result;
}

function get_cat_products($cat)
{
    db_connect();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat='$cat' ORDER BY id DESC";    
    $result = mysql_query($query);    
    $result = db_result_to_array($result);

    return $result;
}
function get_cat()
{
    db_connect();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id DESC";    
    $result = mysql_query($query);    
    $result = db_result_to_array($result);

    return $result;
}

function get_product($id)
{
    db_connect();

    $query = ("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id' ");    
    $result = mysql_query($query);    
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    return $row;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это значит что **`mysql_fetch_array($result)`** не отрабатывает.

Т.е. не передается возможно сам `$result`. покажи вывод того откуда ты вызываешь эту функцию.

```
function db_result_to_array($result)
{
    $res_array = array();

    $count = 0;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $res_array[$count] = $row;
        $count++;
    }
    return $res_array;
}
```

Comment: простите, но  я не понимаю(((

Comment: написал же "Покажи вывод того откуда ты вызываешь эту функцию."

Comment: <?
include('db_fns.php');
include('cart_fns.php');
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
{
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
    $_SESSION['total_items'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['total_price'] = '0.00';
}

$view = empty($_GET['view']) ? 'index' : $_GET['view'];

  
    
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/shop/views/layouts/shop.php');


?>

Comment: Это явно не тот код.

Я же написал, нужен код, в котором идет вызов ф-и **db_result_to_array** а не подключение их

Comment: switch($view)
{
   case('index'):
   $products = get_products();
   break;
   
   case('cat'):
   $cat = $_GET['id'];
   $products = get_cat_products($cat);
   break; 
   
   case('product'):
   $id = $_GET['id'];
  $product = get_product($id);
   break; 
   
   
      

    
}